# wondershaper bandwdith limit per ip

Tags: bandwidth, tc

Does this command allows us to download speed 512kpbs for each connected devices? or let say if two devices connected then they get  only 256kbps each or 512 kbps each ?

> sudo wondershaper wlan0 512

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`wondershaper` works on interfaces only, not on different systems using the router. It is a simple tool, and your requirement is too complex for what it offers.

You either have to configure that manually or find a different tool which offers that. `shorewall` has tc capabilities and can work with destination IP addresses but I do not know whether you can enforce that all get the same share.